# False positive "Unreachable code detected.ts(7027)"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Following snippet returns `Unreachable code detected.ts(7027)` on `console.log()`. Running on `Visual Studio Code v1.43.2`.

```js
const foo = (() => {
  try {
    // operation like "return fs.readFileSync("./credentials.json")" is more likely to fail (nodejs)
    // following line is just placeholder
    return { val: 4 };
  } catch (err) {
    return { val: -1 };
  }
})();

console.log(foo.val); //vs throws unreachable
```

[TypeScript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUaCUKB8MDeAUDDFAE4CeBxJMZAplAK5lgEwBuAhgDYBcMACwwAvgG4aImMC5RgAC3T0yZbEVp1GLNvk68BAWgCMIyYRGYsEwqEgge9AHQ8QAczQIQj7j0xigA)

Is it really a false positive?

Comment: How would this ever throw an error?

Comment: Also "*I want to calculate foo's value at the declaration time, not later*" that will ALWAYS be the case. If you have async code, then the value would still be calculated at declaration time, it's simply a Promise.

Comment: I guess never. But return value is just a placeholder. You could replace it with some operation.

Comment: So, would that operation throw an error? If not, then the `catch` would be unreachable.

Comment: vscode gives `Unreachable code detected.ts(7027)` warning on `console.log()`, not `catch`.

Comment: This must be a bug with VS Code, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ritaj It seems to be TypeScript [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUaCUKB8MDeAUDDFAE4CeBxJMZAplAK5lgEwBuAhgDYBcMACwwAvgG4aImMC5RgAC3T0yZbEVql5ZEAHcYYenoCiKkGTTLVEkiMIjMWCYVCQQPegDoeIAOZoEIB7cPJhiQA) it does show up there. Strangely, even a `return` in the `catch` block doesn't work [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUaCUKB8MDeAUDDFAE4CeBxJMZAplAK5lgEwBuAhgDYBcMACwwAvgG4aImMC5RgAC3T0yZbEVp1GLNvk68BAWgCMIyYRGYsEwqEgge9AHQ8QAczQIQj7j0xigA)

Comment: The TS bug on the Playground Link doesn't show if you use my answer's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to implement it this way, you'd need to have some sort of fallback for `val` if the catch occurs.

Implement it this way:

```js
const foo = (() => {
  let val = undefined
  try {
    val = 4
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
  return { val }
})();

console.log(foo.val);
```

It may be just an issue with TypeScript, but this will fix the problem. that TS is moaning about.

Comment: If you go inside the `catch` block, it already doesn't return anything, since it just throws an error and thus interrupts the normal flow of operations.

Comment: That is why the `return` line is outside of the `try`/`catch` block.

Comment: But it still doesn't matter - on a `throw` you're still not getting to that `return` statement.

Comment: Right, good point. My bad... I still think it'll fix the TS Error though.